# Why can't I use a long long int type ? c++

Tags: c++, integer

I try

```
long long int l = 42343254325322343224;
```

but to no avail. Why does it tell me, "integer constant is too long." I am using the long long int type which should be able to hold more than 19 digits. Am I doing something wrong here or is there a special secret I do not know of just yet?

Comment: That's more than 2^63.

Comment: Is there a way to make an object of a class hold any number of integers?

Comment: You need 66bits to hold that number. It's not "Number of digits". it's "size of number". 2^64 = 18446744073709551616, and you're way above that.

Comment: @FredRoy, Yes, and it's already been done extremely well. Use an arbitrary precision integer library.

Comment: [boost::multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Boost.Multiprecision at [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

It defines templates and classes to handle larger numbers.

Here is the example from the Boost tutorial:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int128_t v = 1;

// Do some fixed precision arithmetic:
for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 20; ++i)
   v *= i;

std::cout << v << std::endl; // prints 20!

// Repeat at arbitrary precision:
cpp_int u = 1;
for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
   u *= i;

std::cout << u << std::endl; // prints 100!
```

Comment: What would an example look like to store a very large int? I am in the process of downloading the lib now.

Comment: @FredRoy I pasted in an example from their tutorial. 100! is a very large integer.

Comment: Note that if you want to initialize a `cpp_int` with a literal which is too large to fit in a `long long` or an `unsigned long long`, you can use a string literal. e.g. `cpp_int u {"42343254325322343224"};`

Comment: Thanks Wayne. Best answer here! Its going to solve my problem now!

Answer (score 6):

Because it's more, on my x86_64 system, of `2^64`

```
//                                         42343254325322343224
// maximum for 8 byte long long int (2^64) 18446744073709551616
//                    (2^64-1 maximum unsigned representable)
std::cout << sizeof(long long int); // 8
```

you shouldn't confuse the number of digits with the number of bits necessary to represent a number

Comment: Well, it's more than 2^64 regardless of what system you're using. What's relevant is that `long long` is 64 bits wide -- and the maximum value it can old is 2^63-1, not 2^64. In principle, `long long` could be wider than 64 bits on some systems, but it happens to be exactly 64 bits on every system I've heard of that supports it.

Comment: The same for me, never heard of any system which differs

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the value of the integer literal exceeds the acceptable value for type `long long int`

Try the following program that to determine maximum values of types `long long int` and `unsigned long long int`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have gotten the following results at www.ideone.com

```
9223372036854775807
18446744073709551615
```

You can compare it with the value you specified

```
42343254325322343224
```

Take into account that in general case there is no need to specify suffix `ll`  for a integer decimal literal that is so big that can be stored only in type `long long int`  The compiler itself will determine the most appropriate type ( `int` or `long int` or `long long int` ) for the integral decimal literal.

Comment: I got the same results

Comment: @Fred Roy It means that you are trying to use too big decimal literal that can not be stored in an object of type long long int.